# Improve performance when replacing large quantities of text in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this following code in which I am trying to replace out-of-sequence `whitespace` with `comma` in a text file read from a list of textfiles in a folder.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
        var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath, "*.chunk*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                    select new
                    {
                        File = file,
                        Line = line
                    };

        string newPath = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
        if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath + @"\Test");
        }

        foreach (var f in files)
        {

            string path = f.File.ToString();
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
            string s = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, true))
            {
                s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }

            string[] parts = s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            using (File.CreateText(Path.Combine(newPath + @"\Test", filename + ".txt")))
            { }
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(newPath + @"\Test", filename + ".txt")))
            {
                string output = string.Empty;
                foreach (string st in parts)
                {
                    output += st + ",";
                }
                sw.Write(output);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the program and input a folder with 54 files (1MB each size), process starts but has taken over an hour. I've hit `Debug All` and checked the output and it is showing that it is processing but I'm confused if the code is correct as what I expect from the code is to read the first file, make the changes, and save the first file in the folder `Test` and then take the next file and do the same with it. It has taken over 1 hour of processing so far, but I don't see any output file created in the `Test` folder. Program is certainly running and is processing over the data as it shows in the `Debug All` mode - without any errors. No syntax error, but I need help if there are any logical errors?

Comment: Have you tried running it with a single file and stepping through the code?

Comment: Which directory are you browsing to for testing?

Comment: Your query result is not files, but file lines.

Comment: because you are reading a whole file into memory. and splitting such a large string cause problems. also your main problem is here `output += st + ",";` which causes a lot of garbage and memory waste. you need to use `StringBuilder`. i also suggest read each file line by line and do the split.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Can you please show me how to improve it? Thanks

Comment: @SvenGrosen Since I have run it on the folder from last 1 and a half hour, hoping it to finish before I do anything else like that. But yes, your idea is definitely better. Thanks

Comment: @AnthonyGuertin a folder on a desktop.

Comment: @IvanStoev which means I get 1 file in `files`?

Comment: Which means you get one and the same file multiple times. Same for the another file, etc. Why don't you just iterate the result of `EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: what does this have to do with winforms?

Comment: The code which creates the "Test" directory will never be ran because the if statement is checking if folder exists, which it has to exist since it is the selected path. I think you meant if (Directory.Exists(newPath)) and not if (!Directory.Exists(newPath)). If they type into the selectedpath that is a diff story

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to improve performance.

```
var files =  Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath, "*.chunk*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath + @"\Test");

foreach (var path in files)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);

    using (var sw = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(newPath + @"\Test", filename + ".txt")))
    {
        foreach(var s in File.ReadLines(path))
        {
            string[] parts = s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (string st in parts)
            {
                sw.Write(st);
                sw.Write(",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your main problem was here

```
output += st + ",";
```

Because strings are immutable this causes a lot of memory waste and forces garbage collector to collect a lot of garbage and significantly reduces the performance.

Splitting large text is not a good opinion. so read each file line by line to reduce the load.

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing.  Your `StringBuilder` suggestion was correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there are typos. Please help me correct them. `s` in `foreach(var s in reader.ReadLines())` cannot be used because it is being used in `string s = string.Empty;`. Also, `output` in `sw.Write(output.Replace(" ",","));` has never been defined? Thanks.

Comment: @RehanKhan i have updated the answer. sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Why use a `StringBuilder` and not write to the `StreamWriter ` directly?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary `StreamReader` doesn't contain a definition for `ReadLines()` in line `foreach(var s in reader.ReadLines())`. Did you mean `ReadLine()` instead?

Comment: @RehanKhan oops.got it fixed... sorry my brain is not working well right now.

Comment: @RehanKhan if there is other problems here that im not aware of feel free to tell so i can fix it. im not using VS right now so i write it from mind so bear with me ;)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary. Not a problem. Your solution is running without any errors. It has created a new file in `Test` folder, but its writing and erasing from and to the file at the same time. Like I can see that filesize goes up from 0KB to 8KB, then 0KB then 68KB then 128KB and then comes back to 0KB again. This cycle is  going on from last 5 minutes.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Please help me if I'm wrong. `s` in `foreach(var s in File.ReadLines(path))` cannot be used because it is being used in string `s = string.Empty;` so i changed it to `foreach(var item in File.ReadLines(path))` and accordingly in `string[] parts = item.Split(new[] { ' ' }, ...`

Comment: your problem is in `files` too. ive changed it see if it works

Comment: @RehanKhan delete the line `string s = string.Empty;`. fixed

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Working like a charm but making two output files for every 1 input file with 2 different names i.e., `Sample File.log.chunk001` and `Sample File.log.chunk001.txt` as 2 output files for 1 input file (`Sample File.log.chunk001`) ? Sorry.

Comment: @RehanKhan are you sure? delete your `Test` folder and try again. note that you dont need to check condition for creating path. I have tested the code and it works fine. no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

No-one so far has really hit on the real cause of your performance problem in this code. They've certainly gotten close, but there is one bad issue that I think if you remove then you'll find your code is far faster.

The main problem is caused by this code:

```
var files =
    from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
        folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath, "*.chunk*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    from line in File.ReadLines(file)
    select new
    {
        File = file,
        Line = line
    };
```

If you had 1,000 files each with 1,000 lines then this code means that `files` would have 1,000,000 elements.

You then go on to iterate each of these in the `foreach (var f in files)` - meaning that this `foreach` would run each file for as many times as the number of lines in the file.

You're reading and writing each file many many times.

I do agree that the string concatenation would slow down the code, but it would be worthwhile to see what performance improvement you get simply by doing this:

```
    foreach (var f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog_SelectedPath, "*.chunk*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
     ...
    }
```

Now, of course, it would be better to clean up all of the code issues. I would suggest trying it like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    var result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();

    var newPath = Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath, @"\Test");
    if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
    }

    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath, "*.chunk*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        var newFile = Path.Combine(newPath, Path.GetFileName(file) + ".txt");
        var content = File.ReadAllText(file);
        content = String.Join(",", content.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        File.WriteAllText(newFile, content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to string concatenation, a big problem in this code is the Cartesian product of files and lines:

```
from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(...)
from line in File.ReadLines(file)
select new
{
    File = file,
    Line = line
};
```

Terrible!

Try this code please:

```
FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
string path = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;

foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.chunk*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);

    string newPath = path + @"\Test";
    if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
    }

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file, true))
    using (var writer = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(newPath, filename + ".txt")))
    {
        string s;
        while ((s = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] parts = s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (string part in parts)
            {
                writer.Write(part);
                writer.Write(',');
            }
            writer.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my take on it with some extra...

```
        const string testFolder = @"\Test";

        var folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();

        var path = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;

        if (!Directory.Exists(path)) { return; }
        if (!Directory.Exists(path + testFolder)) { Directory.CreateDirectory(path + testFolder); }

        var fileList = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path) where file.Contains(".txt") select file;

        foreach (var f in fileList)
        {
            var fileLines = File.ReadLines(f);
            foreach (var ps in fileLines.Select(l => l.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)))
            {
                var fname = Path.GetFileName(f);
                using (var wf = File.CreateText(path + testFolder + @"\" + fname))
                {
                    foreach (var p in ps)
                    {
                        wf.Write(p);
                        wf.Write(',');
                    }
                    wf.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
```